# Convert YUY2 to YV12

Tags: c++, image-processing, yuv

I am almost sure that this is much simpler than I think it is, but I have been scouring the internet for a much longer time than I care to admit to try and figure out how the frig to convert the two formats.  I am able to extract the Y0, Cb, Y1, Cr data from a stream of unsigned bytes (unsigned char), but I have no idea how these bytes are arranged in [YV12](http://fourcc.org/yuv.php#YV12) - is this document implying that the various values are actually contained in different rows?

I've literally been searching all day for things like "c++ convert YUY2 to YV12," and have turned up absolutely no tutorials or code samples.  I would think that this would have some form of documentation that I could use, but the information seems to be scarce on this particular subject.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like the [linked entry on YUY2](http://fourcc.org/yuv.php#YUY2) together with the [Wikipedia article on YV12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YUV#Y.27UV420p_.28and_Y.27V12_or_YV12.29_to_RGB888_conversion) makes this pretty clear:

- YUY2 stores every two adjacent, horizontal pixels as four bytes, `[Y1, U, Y2, V]`.
- YV12 stores an entire *M* × *N* frame in a contiguous array of `M*N + 2 * (M/2 * N/2)` bytes. Let's call the array `byte frame[M * N * 3 / 2]`. We have:

  - `frame[i]` for `i` in `[0, M * N)` are the *Y*-values of the pixels.
  - `frame[j]` for `j` in `[M * N, M * N * 5/4)` are the *V*-values of each 2 × 2-pixel tile.
  - `frame[j]` for `k` in `[M * N * 5/4, M * N * 6/4)` are the *U*-values of each 2 × 2-pixel tile.

So as you convert from YUY2 to YV12, you have to halve the amount of *U*- and *V*-data, possibly by taking the average of two adjacent rows.

**Example:**

```
byte YUY2Source[M * N * 2] = /* source frame */;
byte YV12Dest[M * N * 3/2];

for (unsigned int i = 0; i != M * N; ++i)
{
    YV12Dest[i] = YUY2Source[2 * i];
}

for (unsigned int j = 0; j != M * N / 4; ++j)
{
    YV12Dest[M * N + j]       = ( YUY2Source[N*(j / N/2    ) + 4 * j + 3]
                                + YUY2Source[N*(j / N/2 + 1) + 4 * j + 3] ) / 2;

    YV12Dest[M * N * 5/4 + j] = ( YUY2Source[N*(j / N/2    ) + 4 * j + 1]
                                + YUY2Source[N*(j / N/2 + 1) + 4 * j + 1] ) / 2;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

1. Separate the Y, U, and V values into separate arrays.
2. Average together the values from the even and odd lines of the U and V arrays to combine two lines into one. This will cut the height of those arrays in half. The Y array will be `w * h`, and the U and V arrays will now be `w/2 * h/2`.
3. Concatenate the Y, V, and U arrays.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I found this information very helpful, in conjunction with Kerrek SB's; too bad I can't mark both.